# Will a landline phone work through an RJ11 to RJ45 adapter into a router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, phone

I have just replaced an old telco-provided all-in-one with an aftermarket unit (TPLink Archer AX23) with no RJ11 phone jack but I wish to continue use of the landline phone that was connected through the old unit.

Given the relationship between the connectors and protocols, I hope that a simple RJ11 to RJ45 adapter would allow the phone to work connected to a free switchport, but all existing search results concern the reverse (using old RJ11 phone connections for ethernet).

Is this the case? Else, is there another simple solution?

Comment: Cable or DSL? If DSL you want a POTS splitter *before* your modem & plug POTS to that. Cable would probably require some kind of VOIP support, which I don't see mentioned for that router. And, no, you can't just plug a regular phone into an Ethernet socket.

Comment: So if I read this correctly you want the router to enable a POTS phone to communicate using VoIP, is that correct?

Comment: DSL vs Cable: neither. Router is connected by ethernet to a fibre internet box.

POTS: as far as I can tell, I beleive that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The RJ45 ports are Ethernet. There is no way a standard landline telephone will work connecting to an Ethernet port. Not only does your telephone have no way to transmit or receive Ethernet packets, the electrical signals are completely incompatible.

Your previous router apparently had POTS (plain old telephone service) hardware with VoIP (voice over Internet protocol) software support. You will need to find a VoIP box which will work with your specific telco service. You’ll need to contact their customer support to see if there are any that they support.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of a telco box with bult-in VOIP. Here [UK] we still have *actual* POTS carrying the phone system [though it probably transitions to VOIP in the local kerbside boxes] even though we have FTTK for the 'internet' side.